# Is there anyway to add same index multiple times in one operation?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, pytorch

Let's say that I have two tensors *value* and *index*, which contain the data and all indexes we need. I want to add one to data in *value* with the corresponding *index*. If an index shows k times in tensor *index*, then this data should be added by k, instead of one.

Here's an example:

```
value = torch.zeros(3) # [0, 0, 0]
index = torch.zeros(10).long() #[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
ret = some_func(value, index) # [10, 0, 0]
```

I know that using a for loop to go through all indexes in *index* could solve the problem, but I just wanna ask if there is more elegant way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can do this is with `scatter_add`:

```
In [54]: value = torch.zeros(3)

In [55]: index = torch.tensor([0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1])

In [56]: value.scatter_add(0, index, torch.ones_like(index, dtype=value.dtype))
Out[56]: tensor([3., 4., 2.])
```

You can use [`scatter_add_`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.scatter_add_.html#torch.Tensor.scatter_add_) to operate on `value` in place.

---

You might find it more efficient to use `bincount()`:

```
In [63]: index = torch.tensor([0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1])

In [64]: counts = index.bincount(minlength=value.shape[0])

In [65]: counts
Out[65]: tensor([3, 4, 2])
```

If in your actual problem, `value` is initialized with 0s, then you're done--just use `counts` as the result.  Otherwise, add `counts` to `value`.